# memoir, remove space before chaptertitle

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, memoir

I'm trying to come up with some simple tikz based chapter style for memoir.

I've gotten to a point where I'm almost happy with the result but there is a space before the chapter title which I haven't been able to remove yet.

Here's my code (to be compiled with `xelatex`)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\tikzchapnum[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, inner sep=10pt, outer sep=0]
    \node[draw=white!80!black, fill=white!80!black, white,
    left, anchor=base east, scale=2, inner sep=4pt] (cn) at (\textwidth,0) {\chapnumfont \rmfamily \thechapter};
    \draw[white!80!black] (cn.south east) -- ++(-\textwidth, 0);
    \draw[red] (0,2) -- ++(0,-\textheight);
    \draw[red] (\textwidth,2) -- ++(0,-\textheight);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\makechapterstyle{grayhandle}{%
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\large\scshape}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\HUGE\scshape\sffamily}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{2\baselineskip}
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{3\baselineskip}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\raggedright\chaptitlefont\MakeLowercase{##1}}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}[1]{%
    \tikzchapnum{##1}
  }
}
\chapterstyle{grayhandle}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

It gives me this result (red lines, commented out in the mwe, show that chapter title is not flush with the textblock)

[image: extra spacing before chapter]

How can I remove that extra spacing before the title?

Comment: How does those read lines show your issues? How are they made? Please be more specific in your question

Comment: @daleif the red lines show that "FIRST" is not flush with the textblock. You can obtain them with `\draw[red] (0,2) -- ++(0,-\textheight); \draw[red] (\textwidth,2) -- ++(0,-\textheight);` inside the tikzpicture block

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `  \renewcommand*\chapterheadstart{}`. But that looks bad since your  is an overlay and thus have no size. BTW: this design is more or less doable without tikz

Comment: Then make sure that is added in the MWE. That probably comes from the inner sep inside the tikz node.

Comment: @daleif chapter title is not a tikz node though. Tikz is used only for the chapter num. Anyway, see the edit, now the red lines are there, commented out

Comment: `\chapterheadstart` deals with vertical spacing as far as I can tell

Comment: My bad, as mentioned your question is not very clear, I'll look at it again later. But please update it with the markers. Also a good idea to make the mwe not use fonts that others do not have access to. The fonts seem irrelevant to the problem

Comment: Isn't it the space after `\tikzchapnum{##1}` try ending that line with a %. Print chapternum is executed right before printchaptertitle, so if it leaves stuff behind it shows.

Comment: @daleif you're right, there's a space there, and one after `\end{tikzpicture}`! thank you, if you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it. Give me a couple of minutes and I'll update the mwe with a more minimal one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is a sporadic space after this line

```
 \tikzchapnum{##1}
```

The `\printchapternum` is executed before `\printchaptertitle`, thus everything left by it gets interpreted. Use

```
 \tikzchapnum{##1}%
```

instead